# kibana 4: line chart of proportion of items with term matching string over time

Tags: charts, kibana, percentage, linechart, kibana-4

My data has a field called `contents`, which can either have the value `no_contents` or it can have actual data. How might I create a histogram (e.g. by month) displaying what **percentage** of data has `no_contents` or `NOT no contents`?

This percentage calculation is automatically revealed in the tooltip in the pie-chart when doing a "filter" such that `filter1 = no_contents` and `filter2 = NOT no_contents`. Then for the pie-chart I can do a split-chart by "date histogram", and that is *almost* what I want. However, I would prefer to visualize the data as a line chart rather than a pie chart. How can this be achieved?